# How can I convert XML attributes to Excel?

Tags: excel, xml, attributes, converters

I need to see the XML attributes because i have to modify the translation name where type="unfinished".
If i remove the 'type' attribute, the program is working perfect.

Does anyone know how should i modify this code?

```
            xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("original.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
            ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
            if (xlApp == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!");
                return;
            }
            else
            { 
                for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                    {
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();

                    }
                }

            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("original2.xlsx");
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlApp);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);

            MessageBox.Show("Conversion Completed !! ");

            }
```

This is a part of the XML file:

```
 <message>
      <source>Alarms and conditions</source>
      <translation type="unfinished">Alarms and conditions</translation>
    </message>

    <message>
      <source>All other aggregates</source>
      <translation type="unfinished">All other aggregates</translation>
    </message>
```